# How to animate full screen stripes moving from left to right

Tags: android, android-animation

I would like to create an animation but I don't know how to get started with it.
[Here](http://www.packagingsource.com/resize/images/RedWhite-Stripe-Gift-Wrap.jpg?lr=t&bw=1000&w=1000&bh=1000&h=1000)'s this image.

I want the red and with stripes to animate from left to right.
(Translate)Animations are not new to me. Moving an object on the screen is easy, because we have a background behind it. In my case it's the background that should be moving.

If I use an image then there will be no way to fill the empty space the image leaves behind while moving to the right. One idea is to fill the screen initially with the stripes programmatically, start moving them from left to right and when one starts leaving the screen then draw a new line on the left but considering the stripes are not 1px wide I don't know how to do this.

Another way would be to use an image that is wider by 2 stripes than the screen. The 2 stripes are invisible on the left. Once the image is moved to the right (end of animation), we restart the animation. I wonder if that would cause any interruption or will it look like smooth to the user.

Any ideas? Should I use andengine or something similar for this?

Comment: How about: create a white background. Add red rectangles equally spaced across the screen of the required width. Create an additional rectangle one rectangles width off the left of the screen. Translate the location of all stripes one pixel to the right and loop for the number of times equal to the stipe width in pixels. Then start again as you will be back at your starting image again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom drawable that just draws rectangles to the canvas. Following is a basic sample, just use it like

```
BackgroundDrawable bg = new BackgroundDrawable();
anyView.setBackground(bg);
bg.start();
```

Here is the basic working implementation:

```
public class BackgroundDrawable extends Drawable implements Runnable, Animatable {
    private static final long FRAME_DELAY = 1000 / 60;
    private boolean mRunning = false;
    private long mStartTime;
    private int mDuration = 1000;

    private Paint mPaint;
    private int mStripes = 7;


    private void init() {
        if (mPaint == null) {
            mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        Rect bounds = getBounds();
        if (isRunning()) {
            // animation in progress
            final int save = canvas.save();

            long timeDiff = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - mStartTime;
            canvas.clipRect(bounds);

            float progress = ((float) timeDiff) / ((float) mDuration); // 0..1

            float width = bounds.width() / (mStripes * 2);

            for (int i = 0; i < mStripes * 2 + 2; i++) {
                mPaint.setColor(i % 2 == 0 ? Color.RED : Color.WHITE);
                canvas.drawRect(bounds.left + width * (i - 1) + progress * 2 * width, bounds.top, bounds.left + width * i + progress * 2* width, bounds.bottom, mPaint);
            }

            canvas.restoreToCount(save);
        } else {
            // todo draw normal
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setBounds(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {

    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        if (mRunning) stop();
        mRunning = true;
        mStartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        invalidateSelf();
        scheduleSelf(this, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + FRAME_DELAY);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        unscheduleSelf(this);
        mRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return mRunning;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        invalidateSelf();
        long uptimeMillis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (uptimeMillis + FRAME_DELAY < mStartTime + mDuration) {
            scheduleSelf(this, uptimeMillis + FRAME_DELAY);
        } else {
            mRunning = false;
            start();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I wrote a detailed explanation on drawables and basic animation handling here: [Custom drawables and animations](http://blog.davidmedenjak.com/android/2016/01/05/custom-drawable-animation.html).

Comment: Where do I put the `findViewById(R.id.background).setBackground(bg);
bg.start();` part? And what is bg? I can't see such implementation in the sample app on github

Comment: @erdomester Just updated the anser: `anyView` would be the view you want the background in (your root view probably), just set the background and call start on the object :)

Comment: In the meantime I figured it out. It was easy I was just impatient. Can you tell me why is the first drawn line gray?

Comment: @erdomester the only colors used are white and red, so...you probably have some gray background beneath and a margin on the view with that animated background?

Comment: That's strange. When I set a yellow background for the activity then the screen is yellow. When I set the BackgroundDrawable as the layout then the first stripe is always grey, then it turns white. Maybe that's the default color of the drawable? It looks like it's grey until the whole stripe is visible.

Comment: @erdomester I honestly don't know. I don't see why it would be gray, since just red and white are used and if nothing gets drawn it would be transparent. You could just try and attach a debugger and check the state of the bounds as they might not span the whole area of your view. in my test setup I set the background on the root view (a LinearLayout) in `onCreate`

Comment: Figured it out. It's the default color of the canvas so you need to add `canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);` in the `draw()` method. Until the stripe is not fully visible (produced), Android displays it in the default color. Many thanks for the code that I only had to copy paste. Still, I start playing with the canvas because it seems to fun.

Answer (score 0):

You can either go for a custom view or a custom drawable and paint your stripes on a canvas in the onDraw() method